# How to customize leaflet style function to get color depending on properties values

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, leaflet, geojson, folium

I have a dimension called length on geojson properties. I have a drop down list and want to filter by length for example and get different layers colors.

```
function getColor_by_length(d){
    return d > 9 ? '#800026' :
           d > 5 ? '#BD0026' :
           d > 3 ? '#E31A1C' :
           d > 0 ? '#FC4E2A' :
                   '#FFEDA0';
}

function linkDropDown(){
    var linkSelector = document.getElementById('linkSelector')    
    if (linkSelector.value == "length"){
        geo_json_layer.eachLayer(function (layer) {
            layer.setStyle({fillColor: getColor_by_length(layer.feature.properties.length)})
        });
    }
```

I always get only one and same color for all my layer. I couldn't figure out where I am wrong. Any idea please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getColor_by_length` doesn't actually return anything.  Calling `getColor_by_length(something)` is always `undefined`.  You need to do this:

```
function getColor_by_length(d){
  return d > 9 ? '#800026' :   // <----- return the value
         d > 5 ? '#BD0026' :
         d > 3 ? '#E31A1C' :
         d > 0 ? '#FC4E2A' :
                 '#FFEDA0';
}
```

That should do it for you.  Assuming the arguments for `d` are what you think they are.

Comment: Thanks, I forget the return keyword in my post. Even, it does not work. It's like it consider the last condition (d>0) for all the values

Comment: In that case, the values of `d` probably aren't what you think they are.  Check those values and you're likely to find the issue.

Comment: this my code  https://jsfiddle.net/aba2s/0cu5pbf7/2/                                                                                                     I checked values, they seems to be good. I even convert them to int. I don't know why lanes it work but not with length and speed. Could you please help me. I have tomorrow a presentation about it? Best

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm *supposed* to be seeing in that fiddle, but the reason lanes was working and not length and speed is because, again, you were not ***returning*** any value from `getColor_by_length` or `getColor_by_speed`.  [Here is a working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/slutske/tv7y4nrj/11/).  The colors do indeed change now.  I threw a console.log statement in each function too...looks like capacity always returns undefined

Comment: Lots of thanks Seth Lutske, This is  working. It's was due to the return key. I need some holidays

Comment: If this was the answer, please mark it as such so that this question has an official answer